# Data Not Available

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, beta-managed-package

I am trying to install a managed package created from  my own dev org into a new org, I faced an issue. 
"The data you were trying to access could not be found. It may be due to another user deleting the data or a system error. If you know the data is not deleted but cannot access it, please look at our support page."
Any workarounds around this?

Answer (score 2):

Packages take time to propagate across all servers. Try your install again later (in like an hour).

Comment: Its more than an hour and its not helping me

Comment: My managed package involves a controller class, test class and 5 static resources and my component.Please help me out.

Comment: If it's still not available, contact support. There's nothing nobody here can do for you.